# Installing Audiveris OCR for music notation

Tags: music, scanner, notation

I am trying to install the Audiveris OCR for music notation.
As a part of the installation I have installed the Microsoft VC++ environment as noted in the instructions below.

My question is about the 2nd part of the instructions:
"**The system environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX to be set to /ocr/ (including the final "/" character) so that Tesseract software can retrieve its own data**."

Where and how do I do this?

Thanks.

This is taken from the Audiveris site:

```
*   Microsoft VC++ 2008 to be installed beforehand (the free express edition is fine).
* The system environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX to be set to <install-dir>/ocr/ (including the final "/" character) so that Tesseract software can retrieve its own data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the kb http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311843 for windows 2000 but I don't think that area has changed much over the years.

> This step-by-step article describes how to create system variables and how to view system variable information in a Windows 2000 environment. A member of the administrators group will complete all procedures.
>
> Creating a System Variable

```
1. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
2. Double-click System.
3. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
4. Under System variables, click New.
5. In the Variable Name box type the name for your variable, in the Variable Value   
   box type your variable path, and then click OK.
6. Click OK.
```

> Removing a System Variable

```
1. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
2. Double-click System.
3. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
4. In the System variables box, click the variable you want to remove, and then 
   click Delete.
5. Click OK.
```

> Viewing System Variables

```
1. Click Start, point to Programs, Administrative Tools, and then click Computer
   Management.
2. In the console tree, click to expand System Information, click to expand Software 
   Environment, and then click Environment Variables.
3. The display pane to the right lists all current system variables and their
   associated values.
```

> Saving System Variables in a Text Document

```
1. In the Computer Management snap-in console tree, right-click Environment Variables, 
   and then click Save As Text File.
2. In the File name box, type the name you are giving to the file, and then click Save.
```

Comment: Thanks. I need a bit of time to digest this as I am a real tyro at this.
I managed to get to the proper location. Now I need to understand what to do.

Comment: +1, good link, i can confirm correct for XP as well as 2k.  Vista/Win7 may differ tho.  these instructions would benefit from some reformatting tho.

Comment: Yep it is slightly different on Vista/7

Start->control panel ->System-> on the left hand side will be a link for advanced system settings. 

after that is pretty much the same.

Comment: Xavier, once you are there click new. top copy the TESSDATA_PREFIX in the bottom box copy the path listed

Comment: oops path will be something like c:/program files/Audiveris/OCR/ 
c:/program files (x86)/Audiveris/OCR/ if you are on a 64 bit system. just check the directory to see where it installed itself.  

And make sure to add it under the system variable section.